# I have plenty of divs with same class, that I want to show. This div is inside a div, so like a tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm a noob with jQuery, so I have some problems.

I have many divs generated with a foreach (PHP), like this:

And then, I have some tooltip divs that look like this:

```
    foreach($posts as $post):
        $id = $post['post_id'];
    ?>
        <div id="stor" style="background-color:red; width:100px;">
        <?php echo $post['user'] . " " . $post['contents'] . "<br>";?></div><br>

        <div id="popup" style="display:none; background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px; color:white;"><?php echo $post['date_posted'] .  " " . $post['user']; ?></div>
        <?php
        endforeach; ?>
```

So, on my first "stor" div, I want to hover over so the first "popup" div show the content. I hope I wasn't confusing. I'll explain better if needed!

Comment: You want that behavior for just the *first* stor?

Comment: Using the same "id" values over and over again is not valid.

Comment: change your `id` to class, and use the selector `$('.popup:first')`

Comment: I need to use "this", because if I want to hover the "stor" I want the first "popup". If I hover over the second "stor" I want the second "popup". I wrote something like this:
its a printscreen: https://gyazo.com/1f39700644d16a6dba75416c58a41013

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the `id` to `class`, because `id`s are unique by definition.

Your jQuery would look something like:

```
$('.stor:first').on('mouseover', function(e){
  mouseenter: function () {
    $('.popup:first').show();
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $('.popup:first').hide();       
});
```

**EDIT:**

Based upon your final comment, you actually want:

```
$('.stor').on('mouseover', function(e){
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).find('.popup').show();
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find('.popup').hide();       
});
```

This assumes that there is only one `popup` per `stor`.  Otherwise, use the `:first` pseudoelement.  See the documentation for [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1):

`ID`s must be unique, you should use classes instead. You could achieve this result with css only without jquery.

```css
.stor {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
.stor:hover + .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stor">
  user- contents
  <br>
</div>
<div class="popup">date_posted - user</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want tooltips, this has already been solved in jQueryUI. http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post):
    $id = $post['post_id'];?>

    <div class="stor" style="background-color:red; width:100px;"
    title="<?php echo $post['date_posted'] .  " " . $post['user']; ?>">
    <?php echo $post['user'] . " " . $post['contents'] ;?>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.stor').tooltip();
});
</script>
```